# Error in opencv code: C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to add Gaussian Noise to only a single channel in an image. Here is the code I wrote :

```
  double Mean = 0.0;
  double StdDev = 10.0;
  Mat gauss_noise = Mat(img_a.size(), CV_16SC1);
  randn(gauss_noise, Scalar::all(Mean), Scalar::all(StdDev));

  Mat img_a_noise_planes[3];
  split(img_a, img_a_noise_planes);
  addWeighted(gauss_noise, 1.0, img_a_noise_planes[1], 1.0, 1.0, img_a_noise_planes[1]);

  merge(img_a_noise_planes, 3, img_a);
```

I am having an error on the `addWeighted()` line in the code. 

Error:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (When the input arrays in add/subtract/multiply/divide functions have different types, the output array type must be explicitly specified) in arithm_op, file /home/cortana/Libraries/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp, line 683
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/cortana/Libraries/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:683: error: (-5) When the input arrays in add/subtract/multiply/divide functions have different types, the output array type must be explicitly specified in function arithm_op

Aborted (core dumped)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: 
The color channel value in `img_a_noise_planes[1]` is `1`. So I changed my `addweighted()` function to :

> addWeighted(gauss_noise, 1.0, img_a_noise_planes[1], 1.0, 1.0, img_a_noise_planes[1], 1);

Now the error is :

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth) in merge, file /home/cortana/Libraries/opencv/modules/core/src/convert.cpp, line 222
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/cortana/Libraries/opencv/modules/core/src/convert.cpp:222: error: (-215) mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth in function merge

Aborted (core dumped)
```

In the merge function, each `img_a_noise_planes` have `channel=1` and I have put 3 in there as `img_a` has 3 channels and is made by merging.

Comment: What is the depth of `img_a`? Unless it's `CV_16SC3`, you need to specify the output depth in `addWeighted`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess the `type` of the gaussian `Mat` is the problem here.
If you are not sure of the `img_a` type then you can move the gauss_noise creation and make it dependent on the type of the split channels. For example:

```
Mat gauss_noise = Mat(img_a.size(), img_a_noise_planes[1].type());
```

Comment: I changed my `gauss_noise` definition, it gives the same error as edit

Comment: I removed the changes I had done to addweighted function and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message it looks like img_a_noise_planes was never initalized or set to the size of the input.

Comment: This is probably not the case since the split should do the required allocation